# Return nested for loop first element by predicate using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<Item>` that contains `List<SubItem>` objects inside and I need to return first date of `SubItem`. I'd like to use streams for this. I know that `SubItem` is never null or empty.

Logic behind is to retrieve date from `SubItem` which for all `Item` objects are the same. Loop through `Item` list then loop through `SubItem` (each Item has list of `SubItem`) and from the first `SubItem` return date.

Using non stream:

```
public LocalDate getSubItemDate(List<Item> items) {
    LocalDate date = null;
    for (Item item : items) {
        List<SubItem> subItems = item.getSubItems().getSubItem();
        for (SubItem si: subItems) {
            XMLGregorianCalendar rawDate = si.getSubItemDate().getVal();
            return rawDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate();
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

And using stream I've tried so far and I want to have something like this:

```
// but it's boolean...
public LocalDate getSubItemDate(List<Item> items) {
    return items
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(item -> 
                item.getSubItems().getSubItem()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(si-> 
                    si.getSubItemDate().getVal().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your first code snippet, there is no need to write a *for* loop. You can directly get the first item out of the list after checking the list size.

```
if (items.size() > 0) {
    Item item = items.get(0);
    List<SubItem> subItems = item.getSubItems().getSubItem();
    if (subItems.size() > 0) {
        XMLGregorianCalendar rawDate = subItems.get(0).getSubItemDate().getVal();
        return rawDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate();
    }
}
return null;
```

Using streams,

```
items.stream()
    .findFirst()
    .flatMap(item -> item.getSubItems().getSubItem().stream().findFirst()
               .map(si -> si.getSubItemDate().getVal().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate()))
.orElse(null); //or use orElseThrow to throw an exception
```

Also, using `getSubItems().getSubItem()` sounds odd, it should have been just `getSubItems()`.

Comment: Is there a way to not result in ```null``` using stream?

Comment: As per your code, you were returning a null. That is why I added it. If you are sure the list won't be empty, you can add `orElseThrow` to throw an exception.